# FORCE_COMMON_ALLOCATION in gnu linker scrept

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, ld, linker-scripts

i am reading the gnu linker manual, they mentioned that:

> FORCE_COMMON_ALLOCATION
>   This command has the same effect as the ‘-d’ command-line option: to make
>   ld assign space to common symbols even if a relocatable output file is specified
>   (‘-r’).

i do not understand what they mean with "*assign space to common symbols*", could someone simplify it to me.
thanks.

Comment: Do you know what a common symbol is?

Comment: no, not exactly. @fuz

Comment: first hit on a google search has an explanation

Comment: Then you should find that out first.  Your question should be immediately clear once you understand what common symbols are and how they are treated during linking.

Comment: thank you for your help @fuz

Comment: @old_timer google search ranking is niether constant over time nor the same for all individuals. Maybe you can provide what was the first hit in your search results?